# How to send serialized object from Android Client to Google App Engine Servlet?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

How can i send serialized object from Android Client to Google App Engine Servlet.
i have this code:

```
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() 
{
if (mHttpClient == null) 
{
    mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
}
return mHttpClient;
}

public static String executeHttpPost(String url, Object obj) throws Exception
{    
  HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
  HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
  request.set( ????
}
```

how do i continue from here?
is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);   
out.writeObject(obj);
byte[] yourObjectSerialized = bos.toByteArray();

HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(yourObjectSerialized));
```

Comment: And again, Peter to the rescue.. Dude you ROCK!!
Thanks.
P.S how can i get the byets back from 
HttpServletRequest request

Comment: Please, please don't do this - there are both security and portability implications of sending serialized Java objects around. Use a format you control, like JSON or Protocol Buffers, instead.

Comment: @Nick - I wouldn't do it either, but he explicitly asked for it.

Comment: There's no harm in adding caveats to your answer. If you don't, the OP won't know he's doing something questionable at all.